# Refresh embedded queries in excel each night automatically. Can this be done?

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

It would be a great help for me, if I could update all of the queries, pivot tables, and formulas each morning at 6 AM before I came into work.

I have this code which I got from Stack Overflow which updates the queries automaticaly.

```
Public Sub Refresh()
'refresh
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Refresh"

End Sub
```

I know it updates the queries but I would like to set it to do this at a specific time and then do all the pivot tables and formulas. It would also be nice if it updated a cell with the last time it was updated correctly as a check.

Thanks guys! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You want to launch this via .vbs, I think.  Copy and paste this code into a text file (notepad) and when you save it, change ".txt" to "all files" and save it as "launchMacros.vbs" (or what have you).

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your.xls")

xl.Run "'your.xls'!macro"

wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

Then use windows task scheduler to launch this .vbs file on a computer that has access to the Excel file, and will be awake.  If you're unsure how to use the task scheduler just search the web, it's very common and you'll find a lot of resources for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your macro will perfectly do what you want it to do, with a few small adaptions.

`ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` will indeed refresh all external data ranges and PivotTable reports in the workbook. To calculate formulas, use `Application.Calculate`.

As for the specific time you want the sub executed, `Application.OnTime` accepts a timevalue. So you can insert a timevalue for 6 AM the following day, for example by using:

```
Dim y As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim d As Long

y = Year(Now)
m = Month(Now)
d = Day(Now)

Application.OnTime DateSerial(y, m, d + 1) + TimeSerial(6, 0, 0), "Refresh"
```